# ListView SelectedValue in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, listview

I have a ListView in my WPF application. my ListViewItem s are just Images. but I want to get the selected value of this ListView. In ASP.Net I can set a Text/Value pair for a listitem, and the selectedvalue was the Value I have set.

how can I achieve this in wpf ?

Here is my Xaml :

```
<ListView Name="lstStyle" MouseDoubleClick="lstStyle_MouseDoubleClick" KeyDown="lstStyle_KeyDown">
        <ListViewItem>
            <Image Source="/WPFSample;component/Images/Home1.png"></Image>

        </ListViewItem>
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ListView's `ItemsSource` and bind it to a collection of objects containing your image path and your Id field

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In your ListView's DataContext you would have

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection;
public int SelectedId;
```

where `MyItem` is simply a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Or as an alternative, if you're not interested in good design, just use the `Tag` property of the `ListViewItem`

```
<ListViewItem Tag="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView items should be in binding with a collection in the DataContext. To do that you can use the property ItemsSource. Anoher property, called SelectedItem, can be used to bind the selected item in the ListView to another property in your DataContext.